# How to install openssl 1.1.1 in ubuntu for ARM cross compilation

Tags: openssl, arm, cross-compiling

I have build script for ARM cross compilation and is running on x86 machine. This script has commands as below.

`sudo debootstrap --arch=amd64 --variant=buildd focal /srv/armRoot"`

`echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main universe" >  /etc/apt/sources.list`

`echo "deb [arch=armhf] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal main universe" >>  /etc/apt/sources.list`

`echo "deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main universe" >>  /etc/apt/sources.list`

`sudo apt-get install -y openssl:armhf`

`sudo apt-get install -y  libssl-dev:armhf`

But these commands are installing openssl `3.0.2-0ubuntu1`. But my requirement is openssl 1.1.1 version

What changes are needed in above commands to install 1.1.1 instead of 3.0.2 version of openssl?

Ubuntu version is 20.04(Focal)

Comment: Could you please augment your question with the output for the `lsb_release  -a` command ? this would probably be helpful for determining if the 1.1.1 version of openssl:armhf does exist for the exact  Linux distribution you are using.